# Plural form for noun preceding another noun

Tags: nouns, grammatical-number

I'm working on a web service and we need to create new menu section, which should list entities to configurate different shops' parameters. Which form of this phrase is right in this case and why?

- Shop configuration
- Shops configuration
- Shops' configuration

Comment: Andrew's suggested duplicate is ***the wrong question*** to link it to; it's also a duplicate, and the question it's linked to doesn't answer the OP's question well. I have seen a question that has a good answer for the OP's question, but there are so many similar questions on this site it's hard to find it.

Comment: The form "shop configuration" sounds best to me. You could also grammatically use "shop's configuration", but that doesn't sound as good to me. You should ***not*** use "shops' configuration", because (unlike "users' group"), a configuration is associated to only a ***single*** shop.

Comment: Thanks for reply. The point is there are many shops (pretty homogeneous though) and there are some options to configurate them.

Comment: I've read some articles on plurals and possessives and now I'm just frustrated to choose the right combination for my case. "Users Group" is a bit similar, but configuration is more general entity than group, so I can't directly relate these cases.

Comment: @PeterShor I know that SE don't like linking questions to others which are themselves identified as duplicates, but the question I used as the link **is** the right question: the answers there help here.

Comment: @AndrewLeach Yes, that question helped to see the issue in different perspectives. Also, it has an answer to other questions I haven't sounded yet :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two possible (although very much related) meanings of configuration here.

If you take "configuration" to mean "the act of configuring", only "shop configuration" is grammatical (compare "airplane flying" and "ship navigation").

If you take "configuration" to mean "the result of the act of configuring", then you could use either "shop's configuration" or "shop configuration" (or maybe even "shops' configuration" if you can have one configuration associated with multiple shops).

I would guess that you want to allow for both meanings (because I am assuming that your website lets the users configure the shops), so I would suggest "shop configuration".

Comment: Yes, these are correct guesses.